# how can i make django file upload work with valums/file-uploader

Tags: ajax, django, file-upload, upload

I want to make valums/file-uploader run with django upload, using it with model fields (FileField)

basic django model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.FileField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')
```

basic view, working with non ajax upload:

```
def ajax_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newfile = Image()
        newfile.user = request.user
        file_content = ContentFile(request.FILES['file'].read())
        file_name = request.FILES['file'].name
        newfile.url.save(file_name, file_content)
        results = {'url': newfile.url, 'id': newfile.id}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results))
    raise Http404
```

The problem is that valums uploader does not put the files in "request" files, it put it in the POST, and django get it as a querydic.

Using it with the top code django says:

> "Key 'file' not found in "

If i change:

```
file_content = ContentFile(request.POST)
```

django says:

> expected read buffer, QueryDict found

I can make it work but i still want to hold on django's native file upload, it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`request.body`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/) (or `request.raw_post_data` if older than 1.4)